# how to get the corresponding type from fruit names array?

Tags: javascript

Get the corresponding `type` in the object, and then traverse the array of push objects, but I can't think of a better way to solve the desired result below.

**I want a good return as follows:**

```
[{
"id": 1,
"type": "one",
"name": ["apple","apricot"]
},
{
"id": 3,
"type": "two",
"name": ["avocado"]
}]
```

```js
var result = [{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "one",
    "name": "apple"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "one",
    "name": "apricot"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "two",
    "name": "avocado"
  }
]

Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var hash = {},
    len = this.length,
    result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (!hash[this[i].type]) {
      result.push(this[i].type);
      hash[this[i].type] = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(result)
console.log(result.unique())
var cArr = result.unique()

var arr = []

cArr.forEach(function(prop) {
  result.map(function(item) {
    if (prop == item.type) {
      console.log(item)
      arr.push({
        ...item,
        [`user_${item.id}`]: item.user,
      })
    }
  })
})
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: What if `id:2` would be present already for some other root array item?

Comment: You don’t need an `id:2`.

Comment: I. probably, didn't make my point clear enough: your code produces object, having `id:2` and `name:'apricot'`. My question was: what if source array contain item with `name: avocado` **and** `id:2`? And, one more, it is not stated explicitly within your question body, are some of the properties should be unique within resulting array? What if second item of your source array had `name: ['avocado', 'apricot']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) quite easily:

```js
var input = [
  { id: 1, type: "one", name: "apple"},
  { id: 2, type: "one", name: "apricot" },
  { id: 3, type: "two", name: "avocado" }
];

// Make sure `unique` doesn't already exist on the Array prototype
if (!('unique' in Array.prototype)) {
  Array.prototype.unique = function () {

    // iterate over the array
    const temp = this.reduce((acc, current) => {

      // Desstructure the id, type, and name from the current object
      const { id, type, name } = current;

      // If an key with the value of `type` doesn't exist
      // on the accumulator, add a new object with name set
      // to an empty array
      acc[type] = acc[type] || { id, type, name: [] };

      // Push the name in the current object to the name array
      acc[type].name.push(name);

      // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
      return acc;

    // Note: the initial accumulator value is an object
    }, {});

    // Then simply return the values from the accumulated object
    return Object.values(temp);
  }
}

console.log(input.unique())
```